# Help with finding roots of $a^{36}-1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The starting polynomial was $\sum_{k=0}^{35} (x+2)^{35-k} (x-1)^k =0$ I divided by $(x-1)^{35}$ to get $\sum_{k=0}^{35} a^k$, where $a=\frac{x+2}{x-1}$ Then after trial and error I multiplied by $(a-1)$ (got the idea from telescoping series)

I rewrote $a^{36}-1=0$ as $z^2 -1 =0$ where $z=a^{18}$ and repeated this process till I got $y^6-1=0$ which can be factored into 
$$ (y-1)(y+1)(y^2-y+1)(y^2+y+1) =0 $$

This has real roots of $-1,1$

Now this is where I get a bit confused.  From $a^{36}-1=0$ gives $a^{36}=1$ then $\sqrt[36]{a^{36}} = \sqrt[36]{1} \Rightarrow a=1$ which results in $\frac{x+2}{x-1} = 1 \Rightarrow x+2 = x-1 $ which is not valid.

But $x=1$ doesn't solve the original equation. Then I figured that means that $a=-1$ which does give a number; however, I don't have a good reason why this should be true.  Could someone give me some theory or deeper understanding why $a=-1$?

Comment: Do you know roots of unity in complex numbers?

Comment: You multiplied both sides by $(x-1)$ to get a new equation. Of course, this means that $x=1$ will be a solution to the new equation.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey No, I'll google that.  Could you suggest a link to read.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Just couldn't think of another way to make the equation more simple.

Comment: @ElSanti and that's perfectly okay! All it means is that you need to check $a=1$ separately to make sure that it isn't an "extraneous root". Things like this also happen, for example, when you square both sides of an equation.

Comment: @ElSanti, You simply use [*De Moivre's Theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula). Your equation is $$a=1^{\frac 1{36}}=\left(\cos 0+i\sin 0\right)^{\frac 1{36}}=\left(\cos \frac {2k\pi}{36}+i\sin \frac {2k\pi}{36}\right)$$, where $k=0,1,2,\dots ,35$. Now, can you do this?

Comment: @Subhadeep read the question more carefully. The asker is looking for real solutions.

Comment: In my first comment, I meant to write $a$ instead of $x$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, here I stated this because from this, you can get all the solutions to this equation. And a simple intuition gives you the idea that, at $k=0$ and $k=18$, you can get the only two real solutions which are $1$ and $-1$. Mind it $\Bbb R\subset \Bbb C$.